# windowbuilder how to highlight a text entry

Tags: windowbuilder

in windowbuilder i have a textentry field.
in case the entry is invalid i display the message and want to highlight that it is selected.
the following code works that it does all, but highlighting:

```
              txtSoftwareId.setForeground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
              txtSoftwareId.setText(errorMsg);
              txtSoftwareId.selectAll();
              txtSoftwareId.setFocus();
              txtSoftwareId.showSelection();
```

if i start typing it will delete the entry as it should. only thing is i would like to highlight.
i tried the background color, but that would change the textfield background but not the text background.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Can I ask if it's RCP 3 or 4 platform that you're working with? I wonder if the bug is "ported" the latter one.

Comment: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Answer (score 0):

I also run into this once, it's a known bug on Windows and 3.X Eclipse platform. Has a workaround, see [here.](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=46059)

Comment: not 3.x platform, Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), running on ubuntu not windows.
also it is not a button but a text input field.
no listener needed, just change the text background and select the text,put focus, so if the user types it overwrites the system displayed text.
as i said it works, just you cannot see it is selected.

Comment: The bug mentions no button at all. I understand your problem exactly, and now I'm quite sure it still exist even on the 4.x platform.